# Pending Extrinsic not executed on block producing parachain

Tags: parachain, ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, cumulus

I have followed the [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/) and have reached the step where parachain is now producing and finalising block with a local relay chain. Transactions on chain and DMP (teleport asset) all works well. I used the recent v0.9.24 parachain [template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/tree/polkadot-v0.9.24).

I then follow the tutorial and [added the contract-pallet](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/) (following the impl in the node and runtime on the [v0.9.24](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.24/bin/node/runtime) branch, whilst blocks are still being produced on the parachain and being finalised, simple extrinsics such as transfer are now "stuck" in tx pool in the node, i.e. it is just in the pending extrinsic section of the UI, until the the signature dies after mortal period.

Any info would be much appreciated, thanks!

---

Update:
I have logged the trace and I am getting

```
2022-07-03 11:42:00.152 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Parachain] [0x84d762e40aa5d13c850d8784b6d2a9432a02322d31248ddf8ad8ada5f311c677] Reported as invalid. Will skip sub-chains while iterating.
2022-07-03 11:42:00.152 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship: [Parachain] Block seems full, but will try 7 more transactions before quitting.
```

Perhaps I need up increase block size? I don't understand why this would be the case though. Thanks

Comment: can you hare your source?

Comment: for reference, this is the common good minimal contracts parachain https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/runtimes/contracts/contracts-rococo

Answer (score 1):

A case of how this can happen is this:

You chose a gas limit that is larger than the entire block weight.

The "gas limit" is referring to the weight that the node assumes for executing the extrinsic. If this limit is larger than the block weight the node would be unable to put your extrinsic into the block.

Could this be the case for you?

The UI's (https://contracts-ui.substrate.io and `polkadot-js`) both dry-run the extrinsic on the node and show you the gas costs of that dry-run. They prefill the field for "gas limit" with this value. So you shouldn't run into this case if you use just the default settings.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with ALL extrinsic: polkadot-sdk/substrate, master branch. https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/tree/optimize_9.40